# Struggling to comprehend this while loop

Tags: python

```
num_list = [422, 136, 524, 85, 96, 719, 85, 92, 10, 17, 312, 542, 87, 23, 86, 191, 116, 35, 173, 45, 149, 59, 84, 69, 113, 166]

count_odd = 0
list_sum = 0
i = 0
len_num_list = len(num_list)

while (count_odd < 5) and (i < len_num_list): 
    if num_list[i] % 2 != 0:
        list_sum += num_list[i]
        count_odd += 1
    i += 1

print ("The numbers of odd numbers added are: {}".format(count_odd))
print ("The sum of the odd numbers added is: {}".format(list_sum))
```

Disclaimer: I'm a complete beginner and I find myself struggling most with while loops. For loops make sense to me.
The purpose of this code is to get the first 5 odd numbers in the list and find their sum.
I'm struggling to understand the purpose of the `i` variable and why they used `num_list[i] % 2 != 0` (if i is set to 0 globally before the loop) to find the odd number. I'm guessing it mimics a for loop so it can iterate over the list but I'm not sure how it works. and the block of code beneath that

```
list_sum += num_list[i]
count_odd += 1
i += 1
```

is what I'm struggling with most. I don't understand what this block of code is meant to achieve and how it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop continues to loop as long as the `count_odd` variable (number of odd numbers evaluated so far) is less than 5 **and** `i` (total number of numbers evaluated so far) is less than the length of the the list of numbers to evaluate.

Each time the code runs, if the number at the current index (`i`) is odd (has no remainder after being divided by 0) then the sum of the odd numbers (`list_sum`) is increased by the value of that number. Also the number of odd numbers evaluated (`count_odd`) is increase by 1 to show that another odd number is evaluated. But no matter whether or not it is an odd number, the index of the current number (`i`) is increased by 1 to show that the next number can be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

The code is preatty simple:

The condition on the wile mean that while he hasn't find 5 number, and while there are number in the first list, it has to work.

Than the condition:

```
if num_list[i] % 2 != 0:
```

The variabile is used to read each element of the list, while the variabile increase itself.

Then num % 2 return the
remainder of the division num/2. If it is not 0, It will be 1 for sure, so the number is odd.

The variabile increase itself because it has to read the next number in the list. If it isn't fine for you, try to learn something about list, tuples and so on

Hope will be useful

Answer (score 0):

```
#it is the first initializing, essentially starting with 0
i = 0
len_num_list = len(num_list)

# you can reframe the while to:
# as long as you do not have 5 odd numbers AND you are not through the whole list, continue
while (count_odd < 5) and (i < len_num_list):
    # num_list[i] means that you take the element with index i from the list
    # since i is initialized with 0, at the first loop you take the first element (in python index starts at 0 not 1)
    # SomeNumber % 2 means that if you divide the number by 2, what are the decimals.
    # Only odd numbers will have decimals after division with 2, e.g. 4/2 = 2.0 but 3/2 = 1.5 so the rest would be 5
    # and 5 is != 0
    if num_list[i] % 2 != 0:
        # number += other_number is essentially short for: number = number + other_number
        # essentially you have e.g. numb = 100 and want to add 10, you can either do:
        # numb = numb + 10 OR numb += 10
        list_sum += num_list[i]
        count_odd += 1
    # since we are now through the first number of the list, which had index 0
    # we now add 1 to the index and the while loop continues until the criterias stated after the "while" keyword are met.
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to 'for' loop separating the condition checks. Indexing the num_list is unnecessary, it can be iterated over.

```
for n in num_list: 
     if n%2==0: 
         continue 
     if count_odd==5: 
         break 
     list_sum+= n 
     count_odd+= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable i is the variable that runs the while loop.
In the code initial i=0,and the use of (num_list[i] % 2 != 0) is to find the odd number.
Because any number divisible by 2 is a even number.Therefore in the code it is given when the number is divided by 2 it should be not equal to zero.
So it is a odd number.

Explanation of the code.

```
num_list[0]=422
422/2 is equal to zero.so it is not a odd number.
Then the i value is incriminating by 1
So i=i+1
i=0+1
i=1
now the value of i=1
num_list[1]=136
136/2=0 it is a even number.
Now i will again incriminating by 1
i=1+1
i=2
num_list[2]=524
524 is again even.
Then i again incriminating by 1
i=2+1
i=3
num_list[3]=85
85/2 is not zero
then list_sum=0+85
now list_sum=85
And i keeps on incriminating by 1 till 5 odd numbers is achieved.
```

*Here is the same code with for loop*

```
num_list = [422, 136, 524, 85, 96, 719, 85, 92, 10, 17, 312, 542, 87, 23, 86, 191, 116, 35, 173, 45, 149, 59, 84, 69, 113, 166]

countodd=0
sum=0
l=len(num_list)
for i in range(l):
    if countodd<5 and  num_list[i] % 2 != 0:
        sum+=num_list[i]
        countodd+=1
print("The numbers of odd numbers are",countodd)
print("The sum of the odd numbers is",sum)
```

Comment: @S0V22 u r so welcome.And please cast a vote for my answer.